# Get Paypal Payment type (Paypal or Creditcard) from IPN response

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

i am just testing(sandbox) Paypal using "buy now button". i am able to send a payment request and getting a notification from paypal.

on success i would like to update that order by setting a payment way(paypal, creditcard, ...etc). but i cannot find anything about this documented.

is this possible? if yes which variable name should i ask?

i searched long time here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#id08CKFJ00JYK

AND here

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id08CTB0S055Z

but cannot find how!

what i am doing is:

1. buyer press on pay now button
2. redirected to paypal
3. now buyer may pay using PayPal OR Creditcard
4. on complete i get a notification from Paypal
5. i validate this and if VERIFIED i update my Database
6. **now i would like to know (for statistical use) if buyer paid using paypal or credit cards.**

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: @EJP: i said, its working just fine, but how can i determine(find out) which payment option choosed the buyer on paypal website: payment using paypal account or credit card without paypal account?

Comment: Sigh. What differences did you find in the IPN data between the two cases?

Comment: Is this still not possible through the API ?

Answer (score 0):

If the person paid through PayPal's checkout pages (ie. PayPal Standard, Express Checkout, Adaptive Payments, etc.) you won't be able to determine what their funding source was.

If you are using Payments Pro to process transactions in addition to Express Checkout, though, then those IPNs would have a receipt_id that PayPal wallet transactions would not have.  This way you could at least determine whether they used Pro or Express Checkout.

That said, you could easily add some tracking of some sort to your own code to determine that separation as well.  Again, though, you will not be able to determine what funding source was used if the person pays through PayPal's pages.